# Probleme with my event gesture SDL C

Tags: c, events, sdl

I develop a game written in c and using SDL.
in my main loop when a press a key, it handle more than one time, and I want handle it just on time when I type on it.
I don't know how to fix this problem
Idealy I want to limit this event one time each 5 secondes for example. How I can do this ?

There is my event  file

event.h

```
    #ifndef __EVENT_H__
    #define __EVENT_H__

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

typedef struct s_event
{
    int mouse_x;
    int mouse_y;
    char    key[SDLK_LAST];
    char    mouse_buttons[8];
    int quit;

}               t_event;

void    loop_events(t_event *input_manager);
void    switcher(SDL_Event *event, t_event *input_manager);
void    event_initialize(t_event *input_manager);


#endif
```

event.c

```
#include "event.h"

void    loop_events(t_event *input_manager)
{
    SDL_Event   event;

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switcher(&event, input_manager);
    }
}

void    switcher(SDL_Event *event, t_event *input_manager)
{
        switch (event->type)
        {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            input_manager->key[event->key.keysym.sym]=1;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            input_manager->key[event->key.keysym.sym]=0;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            input_manager->mouse_x=event->motion.x;
            input_manager->mouse_y=event->motion.y;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            input_manager->mouse_buttons[event->button.button]=1;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if (event->button.button!=SDL_BUTTON_WHEELUP && event->button.button!=SDL_BUTTON_WHEELDOWN)
                input_manager->mouse_buttons[event->button.button]=0;
            break;
        case SDL_QUIT:
            input_manager->quit = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
}

void    event_initialize(t_event *input_manager)
{
    memset(input_manager, 0, sizeof(t_event));
    input_manager->mouse_buttons[SDL_BUTTON_WHEELUP] = 0;
    input_manager->mouse_buttons[SDL_BUTTON_WHEELDOWN] = 0;
}
```

my game loop

```
while(!event.key[SDLK_ESCAPE] && !event.quit)
  {
   loop_events(&event);
   move_player(player, &event, world);
   display_world(world, screen);
   fire(player, &event, screen);

   display_player(screen, player, world);
   SDL_Delay(5);
   SDL_Flip(screen);
  }
```

and the function where I want handle my event just one time when I type

```
void  fire(t_player *player, t_event *event,  SDL_Surface *screen)
{

  if (event->key[SDLK_SPACE])
  {
    if (count_list(player->weapon_data) == 0)
       weapon_id_counter = 0; 
      t_weapon *new;
       new = malloc(sizeof(t_weapon));
       new->on_launch = bitmap_loader("resources/kirby.bmp");
       new->shape.x = player->shape.x;
       new->shape.y = player->shape.y - player->shape.h;
       new->shape.w = 32;
       new->shape.h = 32;
       printf("FIRRRE");
       new->is_launch = 1;
       new->id =weapon_id_counter++;
       player->weapon_data = add_weapon(new, player->weapon_data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the key is pressed the first time, save the current time. Then if it's pressed again before the time limit, then either put up an error message, or simply ignore the key.

If the time limit has elapsed, then save the current time for the next check.